# I am getting an error when Importing csv file into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv

I am getting an error that says process failed when I try uploading my csv file into postgresql. There is not exact error message code, it only says "Process failed Copying table data 'public.job.posting' on database 'data_analyst_jobs' and server PostgreSQL 15 (localhost:5432)'. I have no clue how to go about finding what the issue is and need some help determining this, as there is no error message so I have no idea what to even look for. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

I tried to upload a csv file called DataAnalystJobs and got a process failed error. I already created the database and table to upload the database into, and suspect the only thing that could be wrong with the data is the selected schema, maybe that could be what is causing the error.

Comment: can you share more details?, such as OS, how you upload the CSV file, o whatever other command that you are using,

Comment: 1) What client are you using to do this? 2) Look at the Posgtres log to see what it reports and copy(**as text**) the error message as update to your question,

Comment: It sounds like you are using a more-broken-than-usual version of pgAdmin4.  (you should tag what client you are using).  Upgrade to a recent version, or better yet use `psql`, the excellent command line tool that comes with PostgreSQL (which is what pgAdmin4 will use on your behalf anyway, just wrapping it behind a GUI).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and was initially unable to find the error message. Here's what helped me solve it:

- the data type of my .csv file did not match some of the data defined in Postgres columns
- I had to change the column with a date to a different date type

I tried to upload a different .csv file and it worked, that's how I figured that the issue must be with my file and data types defined in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because your field settings are not matching to the one you are planning to import. It can be either the datatype or limiting the datatype. For example your datatype is varchar(20) but you import something which is more than 20 character.